# do mobile banners that are partly hidden count

Tags: mobile, banner

I developed a game and I want to integrate it with an ad network. In my game some small objects move around in the screen, and they might occasionally hide a little part of the adView for a short time. If the objects shall hide the ad partly (since they have bigger z-index),  Will there be a problem? Will the ads be counted as successfull impression?

One more question, how many seconds must the ad stay on screen to be counted as an impression?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, there shouldn't be a problem because it's still showing up. You may even get a higher CTR since people might accidentally click on the ad! The ad should be at least there for five seconds, but remember, if you're showing too many impressions it can hurt your CTR and over all your impressions will be worth less to ad networks.

However, ad networks generally comply with what the IAB sets as mobile ad guidelines. In the future, you can check out IAB.net and see what their rules are.